# Converting from Instant to XMLGregorianCalendar and vice-versa without losing precision

Tags: java, java.time.instant, xmlgregoriancalendar

Using, `java.time.Instant` and `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`, I'm trying to convert from one to the other without losing precision.

Why is this test not passing and how to fix it?

```
class FooTest {
    @Test
    void shouldConvertBackToSameInstant() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        Instant initialInstant = Instant.now();
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(String.valueOf(initialInstant));
        Instant convertedInstant = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().toInstant();
        assertEquals(initialInstant, convertedInstant);
    }
}
```

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2021-03-10T08:34:30.700715078Z
Actual   :2021-03-10T08:34:30.700Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why is this test not passing?**

Your `XMLGregorianCalendar` has got the full precision of your `Instant`. It’s your conversion back to `Instant` that is lossy. You are converting to `GregorianCalendar` through the call to `.toGregorianCalendar()`. A `GreogrianCalendar` only has got millisecond precision, so this is where you lose precision.

**How to fix it?**

Just as you go through a `String` for your first conversion, you may do the same for the opposite conversion:

```
    Instant convertedInstant = Instant.parse(xmlGregorianCalendar.toString());
```

Now your test passes (it did on my Java 9).

**Concluding remarks**

`Instant` has got precision up to 9 decimals on the seconds (so nanoseconds). `XMLGregorianCalendar` has got virtually infinite precision. So if you have converted an `Instant` to an `XMLGregorianCalendar`, you know that it hasn’t got precision beyond 9 decimals, so you can safely convert it back. If on the other hand from somewhere you should get an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with still higher precision (10 decimals or more), the conversion I have shown you will fail with a `DateTimeParseException`.